# HDMI to Thunderbolt Display?

Tags: thunderbolt, hdmi, thunderbolt-display, pc

I was given an [Apple Thunderbolt Display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Thunderbolt_Display). I would like to connect my PC laptop to it. The only problem is that the display only supports Thunderbolt (figures).

After lots of research, I cannot find an HDMI to Thunderbolt adaptor. And unless I am mistaken, Thunderbolt 2 does NOT support DisplayPort. I do not care about taking advantage of Thunderbolt, meaning no webcam, speakers, and other peripherals.

Does anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Thunderbolt displays require [thunderbolt to work](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/213701/5472). Add a PCI card or see if it can be upgraded to USB 4 which is the same as Thunderbolt 3. [Then the 3 to 2 adapters will work to operate the display](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/273070/apple-thunderbolt-3-to-thunderbolt-2-and-thunderbolt-display).

Sorry there is no other way to make these work. Once you get thunderbolt hardware, [windows can work with Apple products](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/189206/5472).

Essentially, [you have a thunderbolt dock with an embedded display](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/268706/5472) and not a display that uses thunderbolt.